# Showing lines above beginning of document

Tags: scrolling

Editing at the top or bottom of the screen is uncomfortable, so why use `zz` all the time (also `scrolloff`). That works fine in the middle of the document, and in the end, and I can keep the cursor centralized.

However, it seems the beginning of the document cannot be centralized. More precisely, I can't scroll above the first line (while below the last line works fine). Is there anyway to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no fix for this. Vim simply can't go "passed" the first line of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct solution to this unless you play with the internals. However you can use a macro to simulate what you are trying to acheive.

use `:1s/\%^/\="\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"/g <Enter> zz` as the first macro to enter 10 lines above the first line of text and center the screen.

After you are done editing, you can use `:1s/\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n//g` as the second macro to delete the first 10 lines.

More details and explainations can be found here: https://github.com/alphaCTzo7G/stackexchange/blob/master/solution.md

You can clone this and play around with this file and see if it works for you.